# Android: Extracting IMEI number in second Activity gives null string

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities, MainActivity and ReceiveActivity (extends BroadcastReceiver). I am trying to retrieve my IMEI number 
whilst in the second activity (I cannot use an intent here) but I get nothing? This is the relevant MainActivity code:

```
  public String deviceID() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDeviceID;
 }
```

And in ReceiveActivity I just have:

```
  private Context context;
  MainActivity ps2 = new MainActivity();
  try {
     Toast.makeText(context, "IMEI: " + ps2.deviceID,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printstacktrace;
  }
```

And I never get a Toast, presumably because ps2.deviceID is a null string (or possibly the wrong 'context')? Can anybody 
assist please? PS: I am testing this on a real device, not an emulator; and I have READ_PHONE_STATE in the manifest.
I have even tried the following code (from an old post here & changing Context to *Service*) which also crashes the application:

```
     public class ReceiveActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         Toast.makeText(context, "IMEI: " + tMgr.getDeviceID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         ...
```

I have finally managed to get the code below to work(the intent-filter PHONE_STATE was missing) and the Toast message is now correct, but as soon as I assign the value of
*tmgr.getDeviceID()* to *number* the application crashes! This is weird. Here is the new code:

```
 public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 String number;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 try {
    tmgr = (TelephonyManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(context, "IMEI: " + tmgr.getDeviceId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    number = (tmgr.getDeviceId()).trim();   //--The app crashes at this line --
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: why can't you use intent? As your want IMEI in broadcastreceiver you can send broadcast from MainActivity with your customAction and extras containing device IMEI, you also require to specify customAction in AndroidManifest for ReceiveActivity. Also the use of word "second Activity" is misleading as your second Activity i.e. ReceiveActivity is not an Activity class but a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: In the Manifest is the following line: `<receiver android:name=".ReceiveActivity">` so MainActivity in not called when an SMS arrives. Then there is: `<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED />`

Comment: your question is not clear to me. But if you want to display device IMEI in your BroadcastReceiver class then you can do it same way as your did in activity, only change is for getSystemService you have to write context.getSystemService, context is one of the parameter of your onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: If you look at the last 2 lines above this is exactly what I did and it crashed the app! I know it is a _context_ problem somewhere but nothing works yet. I also changed `(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` to `(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` but still no joy..

Comment: This should be there in your BroadcastReceiever onreceive `TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);` This will work as i have used this way in BroadcastReceiever class

Comment: Working now! There was a simple typo in a later line!